# Strange characters for &nbsp; in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, character-encoding

I am getting cross like characters for &nbsp; in IE 11.

The characters show correctly as space in Firefox and Chrome.

[image]

The page has UTF-8 charset and it's correctly set in the <head> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was caused by the font used: "Helvetica New".

Changing the font to Arial solved the problem.

Comment: Most Windows users will never have Helvetica on their computers anyway.